# How to delete cacert by .cer file?

Tags: windows, security, certificate

Because of work, I import a cacert.cer file as a trusted root cert, now I want to delete it.
The problem is I don't know anything about it, how do I delete it?

From `win +R`  -> `certmgr.msc`  I can view all trusted root cert , but I don't know which is the one.

1. I try to delete a cert which have a locker icon left top of cert icon and its provider is  my Computer name.
2. Then I try to import the cert file, hope `a locker icon left top of cert icon and its provider is my Computer name` appear, so that I can make sure that it is. But it doesn't.

So I have two questions:

1. what is the cert I deleted?? Does it matter?

[image]

2. How do I delete the target cert from trusted root ??

Comment: What do you know about the certificate? Yes; It matters which one is deleted

Comment: @Ramhound
I delete an unrelated cert which provider is named the same with my computer name . I don't know wether it would be matter in future .

Comment: If you deleted the certificate that you installed what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound What are you talking about ? They are two different cert, one is mistake deleted , and the other which I want to delete still don't know what it name is .

Comment: What are you talking about? You should edit your question, perhaps with screenshots, to clarify your written text.

Comment: @Ramhound I have described very detailed, how can I get a screenshot after I mistake delete the `a locker icon left top of cert icon and its provider is my Computer name`  ? If I can get that mistake deleted cert back, why I have the first question ? Sorry, I just can't understand why you don't understand me .

Comment: Do you mean a padlock icon  instead of a locker icon (a locker is something you put stuff in). I am not sure we are going to be able to tell you what the certificate was for if you already deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound  Yeah and that cert's provider name is the same as my Computer name. But for now, I didn't find anything go wrong, maybe that cert is not important.

Comment: @Ramhound So the left problem is :  I have a cacert file which I have imported before, but I don't know how to delete it , because of I don't know what it named .

Comment: Install the certificate using the file again, pay attention to the details of the certificate, the  uninstall the certificate by deleting it within certificate manager.

Answer (score 0):

First, to be clear, the extension on a filename does not control the format of the contents, nor vice versa, although Microsoft tries to make you think they do, and much MSware won't work right if they don't match.

There are two very different kinds of certificate: (1) a certificate that identifies *you* and for which you *have the private key* which you can use to authenticate yourself to someone else, where 'you' is sometimes you as a person but often an associated organization, entity or system e.g. that you work for or represent (2) a certificate you use to verify the identies of *other* systems, entities and people; this is often the certificate of a CA (certificate authority) and especially a *root* CA (hence 'Trusted Root CAs') but can sometimes be a particular system or person.

It is certificates of type (1) only that have a padlock on the icon in certmgr, and you should never have the private key of a root CA so these don't belong in Trusted Root CAs; normally they belong in Personal. MS expects type (1) certificates (with private key, and chain) to be in PKCS#12/PFX format in files with extension .pfx or .p12; it expects type (2) certificates to be in X.509 format with extension .cer or .crt, or sometimes in PCKS#7/CMS format with extension .p7b. (On output it *creates* .pfx and .cer respectively, but on input it also recognizes .p12 and .crt.)

If you have a .cer file that contains, as MS expects, an X.509 certificate, just doubleclick it (or select, rightclick, Open) and it will popup a dialog (CryptExtOpenCER in cryptext.dll) that looks like this:
[image: Windows cert popup]

where Issued to and Issued by are the same names you see in certmgr for this cert. (Technically there are two variants of X.509 format, DER and PEM which MS inaccurately labels 'base64'; on output you need to select which, but on input this popup will read either.)